# Mapbox GL JS - Loading image overlays as hidden until needed

Tags: javascript, image, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have several image overlays that I am loading on my map when the map loads. I would like to keep them invisible, or off until a later time. My button to turn the image overlays ON works fine by using the "visibility:visible" attribute but I can't seem to figure out how to set them as invisible when the page loads. Ideally I would like all the source images to be loaded but all invisible.

Here is a snippet of the basic code I am using, note "visibility:none" does not work when loading.

```
topleftmapbox.on('load', function() {
topleftmapbox.addSource("source_KEWX_REFLECTIVITY_SWEEP0_4", {
"type": "image",
"url": "KEWX_REFLECTIVITY_SWEEP0_4.gif",
"coordinates": [
[-101.089551, 30.478839], 
[-99.048840, 30.478839], 
[-99.048840, 28.929093],  
[-101.089551, 28.929093] 
]
})



topleftmapbox.addLayer({
"id": "ID_KEWX_REFLECTIVITY_SWEEP0_4",
"source": "source_KEWX_REFLECTIVITY_SWEEP0_4","type": "raster",
"visibility:none",
"paint": {
"raster-opacity": 0.99,

}
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[visibility](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#layout-raster-visibility) is a layout property, so you would need to use it like this:

`"layout": {"visibility": "none"}`

Comment: Yes, this works. It was just simple syntax issues the whole time. I wish I had your brain for the rest of the project... I would be done by now.